# How can I get a route url pattern by route name in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

So I have a route defined in my web.php, like so....

```
Route::any('/items/{id}/{slug}', 'Items\ItemController@item')->name('items.item');
```

I am trying to make a function where I can get the string pattern for the URL, '/items/{id}/{slug}' from the route by calling it's name...

I assumed this would work.. but it doesn't (it tells me I'm missing the parameters id and slug).

```
// Should assign the string 'items/{id}/{slug}' to the variable.
$url_pattern = route('items.item');
```

I'm using Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the [Route](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/Route.php)'s uri as follows:

```
$url_pattern = app('router')->getRoutes()->getByName('items.item')->uri;
var_dump($url_pattern);
// will return:
// "items/{id}/{slug}"
```

---

You can always create a *faux route*. When you are invoking `route()`, one has to assume you know the params it expects.

If you would like to get it as a string (to be used in JS for example), just pass the names of the params as the params. For example:

```
$url_pattern = route('items.item', ['id' => '{id}', 'slug' => '{slug}']);
// will generate:
// items/{id}/{slug}
```

Comment: Weird, this should work.... But I still get the Missing required parameters error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the parameters in the router function, for example:

```
$url_pattern = route('items.item', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes